# Copy file if it doesn't already exist

Tags: python, file, file-io

I'm fairly new to python, and I'm wondering how I can copy and paste a file from one location to another with first checking to see if the copied file exists in the destination folder?

The reason I want to check if the file exists is this script will be put on a task scheduler and run on a set schedule, so I don't want to be copying everything every single time, just those files that don't exist in the destination folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `os.path.exists(/some/path/)`

Comment: FWIW, I think there's nearly always a better way to handle file creation/deletion/use than `os.path.exists`. In most cases there's another module that handles it more elegantly (as I used in my answer using glob to compare two lists) and if there's not then try/catch does a better job of preventing the race condition. I can't think of any script I've written that uses `os.path.exists` that I couldn't re-write to use `glob` with better functionality.

Comment: @adsmith unless you have some security concerns, there's no reason not to use `os.path.exist`

Comment: Use rsync instead of cp

Answer (score 11):

```
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

SRC_DIR = #your source directory
TARG_DIR = #your target directory

GLOB_PARMS = "*" #maybe "*.pdf" ?

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, GLOB_PARMS)):
    if file not in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARG_DIR, GLOB_PARMS)):
        shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)
    else:
        print("{} exists in {}".format(
            file,os.path.join(os.path.split(TARG_DIR)[-2:])))
        # This is just a print command that outputs to console that the
        # file was already in directory
```

I'm assuming you're trying to send a whole folder over with this command, otherwise `glob` uses pretty easy to understand interface. `glob.glob("*.txt")` will grab all the files with a .txt extension, etc. Shouldn't be too hard to tweak this to exactly what you want.

It's important to note that file copy usually involves a race condition. Basically, time passes between checking to see if the file isn't in TARG_DIR (`if file not in glob.glob(TARG_DIR)`) and actually copying it there (`shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)`). In that amount of time, the file could end up there, which will cause `shutil.copy` to overwrite the file. This may not be your intended functionality, in which case you should look into a different method. I don't know of a good one without some research that will try to copy a file but return an exception if that file already exists.

Try/Except blocks, as another answer mentioned, may be useful here as well if it's possible you won't have write access to the directory when your script runs. `shutil.copy` will return an `IOError` exception if that is the case. I believe glob will just return an empty list if you don't have read access to your source directory (which in turn will feed nothing through the "For" loop, so you won't have any errors there).

EDIT: Apparently glob doesn't work the way I remembered it did, sorry about that.

Comment: In this case, I don't want to copy an entire folder, I want to copy contents within the folder, PDF files.

Comment: That's what this does -- sorry I was unclear. `glob.glob` returns a list of the contents of a folder based on some parameters you give it (`glob.glob(TARG_DIR+"\\*.pdf")` would return a list of files in TARG_DIR with the extension PDF, for instance).

Comment: here is what i've tried and an getting an error:

`import glob
import os.path
import shutil
SRC_DIR = "C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Source"
TARG_DIR = "C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Target"
for file in glob.glob(SRC_DIR):
if file not in glob.glob(TARG_DIR):
        shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)
    else:
        print "exists"`

Comment: Line 10, which is the `shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)`.  Do I need to specify a file type (.pdf)?

Comment: No. Can you paste the stack trace for me?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mboyle\Desktop\CopyPaste.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 81, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Source'`

Comment: For whatever reason you don't have permissions to that folder. It might help to put `print(file)` above `shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)` to help track it down.

Comment: i checked and have full control over both the source and target folders

Comment: did you add that `print` line? what does it print?

Comment: `C:\Users\mboyle\Documents\Source

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mboyle\Desktop\CopyPaste.py", line 11, in <module>
    shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\shutil.py", line 81, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Source'

Comment: Change your print line to `print("File is currently %s" % (file))` and copy/paste the entire output. I don't need the stack trace again -- it's going to be the same. I'm thinking Python isn't pulling the file you want it to.

Comment: i have tried this and it works.  The only problem is i don't believe it will run through and check to see if a the same file currently exists or not, it just copies everything.

`import os
import shutil

dir_src = "C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Source"
dir_dst = "C:\\Users\\mboyle\\Documents\\Target"

for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
        src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)`

Comment: You're right, that code won't check for file existence. I also found the bug in my code -- `glob.glob(this_is_a_dir)` doesn't return the contents of the directory, oops! `glob.glob(root\path\path2\targdir)` returns `['root\\path\\path2\\targdir','root\\path\\path2\\targdirectory']` which isn't what you're looking for. I've updated my answer and it should now run without bugs (at least it did on my system)

Answer (score -1):

In Python, it can often be seen that you will hit errors, known as `exceptions`, when running code. For this reason, the `try/catch` has been deployed.

Here is a snippet of code I use in my day-to-day that **clears files** from a directory, or skips if they do not exist.

```
def DeleteFile(Path_):
    """Deletes saved project AND its corresponding "files" folder."""
    try: #deletes the folder
        os.remove(Path_)
    except OSError:
        pass
    try: #deletes the file, using some fancy python operations to arrive at the filename
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(Path_),os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(Path_))[0])+"_files", True)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

This is a classic example of checking for if a file exists. Instead of *deleting* inside your `try` statement, you could have try to *copy the file*. If it fails, it moves on to `pass`, which just skips the `try/catch` block.

Take note, `try/catch` can be used to catch *any* exception, or it can be used to catch [specific ones](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html). I have `OSError` scrawled in but read through them to be sure that's the one you want. If you have a specific error in a `catch` and the system gives back the wrong kind of error, your `try/catch` will not work the way you want it to. So, be sure. IN best case, be general.

Happy coding!

EDIT: It is worth noting that this `try/catch` system is a very *Pythonic* way to go about things. `try/catch` is very easy and popular, but your situation may call for something different.

EDIT: I'm not sure if it's worth noting this, but I realize my answer doesn't directly tell you *how* to check if a file exists. Instead, it assumes that it does not and proceeds with the operation anyway. If you hit a problem (i.e., it exists and you need to overwrite), you can make it so that it automatically skips over the entire thing and goes onto the next one. Again, this is only one of many methods for accomplishing the same task.

Comment: Upper-case letters in function and variable names are considered bad style in most Python projects: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/